Git merge does not take all files from source branch
I have two branches, 'master' and 'develop'.
Other branches have been merged into 'master'.
Now, when I merge 'master' into 'develop', some files from 'master' are not carried over into 'develop'.
How can I resolve this?
When i merge master into develop, it gives me conflicts:

once solved, some files that are in master (which are not the ones in the screen), are not brought back to develop.
In master, there are commits that involve creating/modifying files that are not merged into develop.
There are no commits that delete these files
How can resolve this?
Thank you

UPDATE
In June, a branch was merged into Develop, and then immediately reverted.
This branch started from master. Could it be that the files I'm referring to were not brought into Develop because of that revert?

the merge:

the revert:

And now, when i merge master into develop, that file exists in Master, but the merge do not carry the AccessTokenController.php

Apparently you have deleted some files which has been modified on master. Most logical resolution of this conflict is keep files deleted (discard changes form master), but it depends on content. It may turn out new logic should be moved to some other file to not introduce regression. Anyway git warns bout this conflict and you have to decide how to resolve it.

hi @MarekR,
I'm not referring to files that have conflicts. After resolving conflicts and completing the merge, some files (which, I repeat, Git doesn't flag as having conflicts) that are in the master branch are not being merged into the develop branch.

Which files? For example RitornilnpsController.php? This file was deleted by your branch.

So, this is the src/Controller directory, in MASTER:
https://snipboard.io/6DknIF.jpg
and this one, in DEVELOP:
https://snipboard.io/RLboxp.jpg
When i merge MASTER into DEVELOP, the AccessTokenController.php, should be in DEVELOP, right?

@MarekR, i have edited the question, i would be glad if you can have a look

@Crashh Depends. Did DEVELOP delete a file called AccessTokenController.php? If so, the merge will not resurrect it. What would help is git log --graph --decorate --oneline --stat develop master. That will show us the true relationship between your two branches, and any files they've changed.

@Schwern no, in DEVELOP, that file was there for the first time in the 'merge FIX-MEMORY-LIMIT into develop' commit, immediately after that merge was reverted. So in develop it was not deleted. Or does git interpret revert as deletion? in that case how can i do? :)

@Crashh If the revert deleted AccessTokenController.php, and the revert is part of develop's history, then as far as Git is concerned develop deleted AccessTokenController.php. We'd need to see the real history to be sure.

@Schwern man, git history is a mess.
The 'Software Architect' has decided that in the develop branch, a section of the application is developed, which will go into production (so in master) who knows when. In the meantime, in master, changes have been made to maintain the old and in develop, changes have been made for new sections (2 years of new changes compared to master). I dont know what to do, next week we have a test with the customer, and I need some changes that were made in master, im hating that guy that has merged and reverted :)

@Crashh Yes, long lived branches are a major headache and should be avoided unless it's part of a coordinated plan like git flow. If you just need some individual commits from master, consider cherry picking them and let the architect bring develop and master into sync.

@Schwern, yeah... the architech will not help us. Thank you anyway

I can't say for sure without the full history, git log --graph --decorate --oneline --stat develop master, but here's what is plausible.

develop branches from master
master added AccessTokenController.php
fix-memory-limit branches from master; it includes AccessTokenController.php
fix-memory-limit merges into develop adding AccessTokenController.php
develop reverts the merge deleting AccessTokenController.php
master is merged into develop

A revert is just a commit, so Git doesn't understand that deleting AccessTokenController.php was due to a revert. All it knows is develop deleted master's AccessTokenController.php so it will not resurrect it. And since AccessTokenController.php hasn't changed there's no conflict.
This is why complex branching structures are to be avoided: they create histories too complex to comprehend.
Let's go through it in steps. We'll start after fix-memory-limit has been merged into develop and then reverted. Your repo looks like this.
R [develop] << deletes AccessTokenController.php
|
M 
|\
3 \
|  9 [fix memory limit]
2  |
|  8
1  |  C [master]
\   \ |
 \   \|
  \   B << adds AccessTokenController.php
   \  |
    \ |
     \|
      A
     ...

M is the merge. R is the reversion. B adds AccessTokenController.php and it was done on master after develop branched.
M brings AccessTokenController.php into develop, but R deletes it. Note that B was not part of develop's history before the merge, now it is.
You merge master into develop.
$ git switch develop
$ git merge master

M2 [develop]
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
|    \
R     | << rm AccessTokenController.php
|     |
M     |
|\    |
3 \   |
|  9  | [fix memory limit]
2  |  |
|  8  |
1  |  C [master]
\   \ |
 \   \|
  \   B << adds AccessTokenController.php
   \  |
    \ |
     \|
      A
     ...

develop sees it deleted AccessTokenController.php, so it does not allow the merge to resurrect it. AccessTokenController.php has not changed since the merge, so it does not create a conflict.

If you have a failed merge, instead of reverting its better to undo the merge commit entirely using git reset. git-reset allows you to move branches around as you like.
Let's go back to just after the first merge.
M [develop]
|\
3 \
|  9 [fix memory limit]
2  |
|  8
1  |  C [master]
\   \ |
 \   \|
  \   B
   \  |
    \ |
     \|
      A
     ...

Instead of reverting, undo the merge. Move develop back to commit 3.
$ git switch develop
$ git reset --hard 3

M 
|\
3 \  [develop]
|  9 [fix memory limit]
2  |
|  8
1  |  C [master]
\   \ |
 \   \|
  \   B
   \  |
    \ |
     \|
      A
     ...

Now it's just as if the merge never happened. While the merge commit is still there, nothing references it; it will eventually be garbage collected.


in develop, after the merge revert, 3 months have passed.

In this case you can't simply reset. If you do you'll lose all the work in those 3 months. You need to do an interactive rebase to remove the merge and revert commits and then replay all the newer commits on top of commit 3.
Let's say your repository looks like this.
100 [develop]
.
.
.
5
|
4
|
R
|
M 
|\
3 \
|  9 [fix memory limit]
2  |
|  8
1  |  C [master]
\   \ |
 \   \|
  \   B
   \  |
    \ |
     \|
      A
     ...

We want to delete R and M to get, effectively, this.
100 [develop]
.
.
.
5
|
4
|
3
|  9 [fix memory limit]
2  |
|  8
1  |  C [master]
\   \ |
 \   \|
  \   B
   \  |
    \ |
     \|
      A
     ...

develop is no longer associated with fix memory limit.
Doing git rebase -i -r 3^ will bring up an editor showing all the commits from 100 back to 3. Simply delete the lines for the merge and reversion. Then Git will rewrite commit 4 on top of commit 3 making a new commit with a new commit ID. It'll rewrite commit 5 on top of the new 4 making a new 5, commit 6 on top of the new 5, and so on until it gets to 100.
However, even though all the commit should have the same content (M and R cancel each other out) they will have different commit IDs. Commit IDs are fundamental to how Git works. This has consequences for anyone else working on develop. You will not be able to simply push your change, you will need to git push --force-with-lease and then others who are working on develop will need to git pull --rebase to update their local repositories. See The Perils Of Rebasing in the Rebasing section of Pro Git.
Rebasing 3 months worth of work could go sideways. Be sure to check your work before pushing. You can always return develop back to its original state with git reset --hard <the original commit>. Be sure to note down the commit ID of develop before rebasing, or tag it.
After the rebase, try merging master into develop and see if it goes better this time.

Okay, got it.
in develop, after the merge revert, 3 months have passed. Is it safe to reset and commit the revert?
So I don't lose all the changes made so far?

@Crashh No, if you reset you'll lose all the work after the revert. Instead you'll have to do an interactive rebase to remove both the merge and the revert, and then Git will rewrite subsequent commits on top of commit 3. Since the merge and revert cancel each other out, this should be safe, but be sure to --rebase-merges to preserve any valid merges into develop.

@Crashh I've added a section on how to do that, but this is advanced stuff and rebasing 3 months worth of commits is bound to have complications. Also, I can't be sure the revert is actually the problem, but it won't hurt to try. The rebase can be undone, as long as you don't push.

tysm, you saved my life!!

@Crashh I'm glad you got it fixed!
